# Keep docker container running after logout

Tags: docker

Apologies if this is blindingly obvious, just a docker enthusiast. I can access my docker container from a remote machine as long as I stay logged in, but if I log out the container stops and is no longer remotely accessible. How do I keep the docker container running when the current user is not actively logged in?

Edit: My apologies for not enough details. Running a dockerized jitsi container. It boots up nicely with "docker start jitsi" and my understanding is "docker start" is already detached (-d) so I can close the shell and the container will continue running and I can connect to it from an external source but if I log out and then try to connect, I can't connect into the jitsi container, I am not precisely sure how to keep the container process running. I've been reading up on it and iterating over some possibilites but no dice so far.

Comment: the container will stop when it's main process stops. Can it be, that the only active process in your container is the shell-session? Then it stops once you exit the shell.

Comment: You should add more info to your question to enable others to help you. Which docker image are you running? How are you starting and connecting to your container?

Comment: How are you running the docker daemon?

Comment: Hi @Andy, how did you end up solving the problem?

Answer (score 4):

OK...

1. You can keeping docker service running with the following command `sudo systemctl enable docker.service`. So, when you restart the server or your development environment, it will keep running.
2. To docker container keep running after restart or log out session, you must run command `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --restart always plantuml/plantuml-server:jetty` for example.

The keywords are `--restart always` which tell docker to restart the container when the system boots.

Comment: For already initialized containers we can use the command `docker update --restart always container_name`. [Docker Update to Policy Restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/#update-a-containers-restart-policy)

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Linux, then you can use `nohup` on the docker process. This should allow the process to keep running, even when the user who started the process logs out.

`nohup (enter the command to run when the user logs out) &`

Note: the ampersand is required at the end.

Update: You can open an interactive session with the container, and run the `nohup` command, instead of running `nohup` with the Docker command.

Comment: Docker is a client/server app. There is typically a persistent dockerd running as root separate from the user login.